# Why is it that every 2-Sylow subgroup of G is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Assuming G is a group, I am wondering why are all the Sylow 2-subgroups of G cyclic. I read [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowapp.pdf) that all the Sylow 2-subgroups are cyclic because they are isomorphic to each other. Please offer some details to the proof.

Comment: which page of the lecture note say that?

Comment: it is in the proof of Theorem 6.9

Comment: The theorem starts by assuming that one 2-Sylow subgroup is cyclic. As all 2-Sylow subgroups are conjugate, they are isomorphic.

Comment: As von Eitzen mentioned above, it is part of the hypothesis of the theorem that $G$ has a cyclic 2-Sylow subgroup. The other 2-Sylow subgroups are conjugate to this cyclic one, hence all are isomorphic to the cyclic one.

Comment: My bad, thank you guys. I misread the hypothesis.